# fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Permission denied)

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, centos, phpmailer

**A PHP Error was encountered**
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Permission denied)

```html
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'user',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Comment: above code is working with my localhost as well on my subdomain but not with my 
 aws lightsail  :(

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Red Hat-derivatives, they come with SELinux enabled by default, and probably `php-fpm` is denied access to create socket. Try checking it by running `grep php /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep denied`.

If so, you can run `/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1` as root, then try to run the code again.

Comment: above code is working with my localhost as well on my subdomain but not with my 
 aws lightsail  :(

Comment: run `[ -f "/etc/redhat-release" ] && getsebool httpd_can_network_connect` as root, and show me the output.

Comment: Append the `-P` flag for the change to be persisted on reboots. `/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`.

Comment: four hours. thats how long i was looking for the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your EMAIL_SMTP_HOST to

```
define("EMAIL_SMTP_HOST", "ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
```

If by chance it doesnt work check your EMAIL_SMTP_PORT it may be different to what you set there

```
define("EMAIL_SMTP_PORT",225O);
```

Lastly check if by chance your SSL Certificate is installed in your server,same to the mail server also make sure your cridentials both "SMTP_USERNAME" and "SMTP_PASSWORD" are correct.

Comment: thanks now error is not showing but i still not get any emails

Comment: @JunaidRaza you are now good to go, now fill the 2 step verification ,,,just follow this tutorial  link http://techstacktutorial.com/sasl-authentication-failed-server-smtp-gmail-com/  NOTE the password google will give you here and the email youll use to sign in in the two step verification are the same youll use at your EMAIL_SMTP cridentials  ,had the same issue long before but the two step verification solved it try

Comment: First check the mail log,,, it will have a clue of where the error is  .                                                  try this command      >          tail -f /var/log/mail.log